# extracting Text non recursively with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

this is the code I'm trying to run :

```
String html = "<a href=\"/name/zola-1\">ZOLA <span class=\"tiny\">(1)</span></a>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); //connect  to the page
Element element = doc.getAllElements().first(); //recive the names elements

System.out.println(element.text()); //prints "ZOLA (1)"
System.out.println(element.ownText()); // prints nothing
```

my goal is to extract only "ZOLA", without the text of the children node, but `ownText` prints nothing...
how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `doc.getAllElements().first()` returns

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <a href="/name/zola-1">ZOLA <span class="tiny">(1)</span></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

while you expect

```
<a href="/name/zola-1">ZOLA <span class="tiny">(1)</span></a>
```

The following should work for you:

```
String html = "<a href=\"/name/zola-1\">ZOLA <span class=\"tiny\">(1)</span></a>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
System.out.println(links.get(0));
System.out.println(links.get(0).ownText());
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="/name/zola-1">ZOLA <span class="tiny">(1)</span></a>
ZOLA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```java
String html = "<a href=\"/name/zola-1\">ZOLA <span class=\"tiny\">(1)</span></a>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element elementA =  doc.selectFirst("a");
System.out.println(elementA.ownText()); // ZOLA
```